# Find the limit by L'hospital rule

Tags: partial-differential-equations, limits-without-lhopital

Finding limit by l'hospital rule

$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{7^{2x}-5^{3x}}{2x - \arctan 3x}
$$

Can anyone to explain me how the L'hospital rule works?

Comment: You can start here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%27H%C3%B4pital%27s_rule

Comment: And again (sorry),  the name should be capitalized: L'Hôpital's rule or L'Hospital's rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{7^{2 x}-5^{3 x}}{2 x-\tan ^{-1}(3 x)}\to\frac{2 \times 7^{2 x} \ln 7 -3 \times 5^{3 x} \ln 5}{2-\displaystyle \frac{3}{9 x^2+1}}$$ No more problem. Compute the limit.

Answer (score 0):

$$L=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{7^{2x}-5^{3x}}{2x-\tan^{-1}3x}$$
D. up and down separtely w.r.t. $x$
$$L=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{2.7^{2x} \ln 7 -3.5^{3x}\ln 5}{2-\frac{3}{1+9x^2}}$$
$$L=-\ln(7^2/5^3)=\ln(49/125).$$